# Journaling app I use through the terminal won't work after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: python, software-center

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 and a journal app I was using (https://jrnl.sh/installation/) is returning this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jrnl", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'six>=1.10.0' distribution was not found and is required by jrnl
```

I have tried to force reinstall it but to no avail. I'm new to Ubuntu so please let me know if there is any crucial detail I've left out.

Comment: Your app is build on Python 3, whereas the default python version for you is 2. Try installing the package `python-is-python3`